# Blockwise pasting from "+ register not working

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, visual-block, x11

UPDATE: I run an X server (XQuartz 2.7.11) on MacOS, which I forward via ssh to any Linux machine I use. The problem seems to be that under XQuartz, the `"+` register does not support blockwise yanking/pasting. Indeed, `:call setreg('+',@+,"b")` does not work (`echo getregtype('+')` still gives `V`). Is there anything that can be done about this? How does vim registers work under the hood? Why does the system clipboard affect whether the `"+` register supports blockwise yanking/pasting?

I am having trouble with blockwise pasting from the "+ register. It works if I run MacOS's default version but on both MacOS or Linux I get the following results when I use the version I have installed via nixpkgs.

I start up vim with `vim -u NONE` and then use `ctrl+v` to select the first three lines in:

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

I then press `"+y` to put the block in the "+ register. I then put the cursor on the line `a` and press `"+p` to paste from the "+ register. Result:

```
1
2
3
a
1
2
3
b
c
```

Any advice?

---

Additional info:

- It works with other registers including `*` (like using `"ay` and `"ap` or `"*y` and `"*p`).
- If I start vim with `vim -u NONE -X` (disable connection to X server):

  - Linux: The register `+` works as expected.
  - MacOS: The register `+` does not work at all.
- MacOS: If I stop the X server (XQuartz 2.7.11) things works as expected.
- After blockwise yank to `"+` respectively to `"a`:

  - `echo getregtype('+')` gives `V`
  - `echo getregtype('a')` gives `^V1`
- I do not use any clipboard manager.

---

vim version on MacOS:

```
$vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 10 2018 05:50:24)
macOS version w/o darwin feat.
Included patches: 1-146
Compiled by root
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               -perl              +vartabs
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           +python            +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +writebackup
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +xim
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xpm
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "
/nix/store/mxb9yfzskiid83j9rv1icw39fnimaiv1-vim_configurable-8.1.0146/share/vim
"
Compilation: see nix-store --read-log /nix/store/mxb9yfzskiid83j9rv1icw39fnimaiv1-vim_configurable-8.1.0146
Linking: see nix-store --read-log /nix/store/mxb9yfzskiid83j9rv1icw39fnimaiv1-vim_configurable-8.1.0146
```

vim version on Linux:

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jan  1 1970 00:00:01)
Included patches: 1-578
Compiled by nixbld
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
+balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
+clientserver      +job               -perl              +vartabs
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visual
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visualextra
+comments          +libcall           +python            +viminfo
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +vreplace
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildignore
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildmenu
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +windows
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +writebackup
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +X11
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xfontset
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +xim
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xpm
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "
/nix/store/dgna8nl8d3nmzxbzjxvv7kqbwyv9f62c-vim_configurable-8.1.0578/share/vim
"
Compilation: see nix-store --read-log /nix/store/dgna8nl8d3nmzxbzjxvv7kqbwyv9f62c-vim_configurable-8.1.0578
Linking: see nix-store --read-log /nix/store/dgna8nl8d3nmzxbzjxvv7kqbwyv9f62c-vim_configurable-8.1.0578
```

Comment: What I get and what is expected is to have a1 | 2 | 3 | ..

Maybe you copied  `<CR>` before?

Comment: @eyalkarni The expected behaviour is to turn the lines `a`, `b`, `c` into `a1`, `b2` and `c3`, respectively.

Comment: Related post: [How can I insert multiple lines in front of the same number of lines in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16323636/438329)

Comment: Hm, perhaps the system clipboard cannot handle block-wise selections? What is the output of `:echo getregtype('+')` after yanking to the `+` register? What when yanking into e.g. register `a`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt See my update to the "Addtional info" section.

Comment: @AndersLundstedt as I understand it, I would say your system clipboard cannot handle blockwise copied content.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes that seems to be the problem and this seems to be confirmed by further testing—see my update on the top of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the ctrl-v before. My .vimrc includes `clipboard+=unnamed`
And it works in MacVim using both "+y and just y.

Comment: @eyalkarni Do you run XQuartz? Does it work in vim? I do not use MacVim.

Comment: I don't use XQuartz. Yes,also in vim. I installed it using brew.